# typeORM orderBy using parameters

Tags: typeorm

I am trying to pass the parameters in orderby clause. order column name and order type. Receiving error when I try below code.

```
    params = validateQueryParams(params);
    const Repository = AppDataSource.getRepository(Cl);
    const query = Repository.createQueryBuilder('cl')

        .select([
            'cl.id AS "Id"',
            'cl.nm AS "Name"',
            'cl.dt_ts AS "date"'
        ])
       .from (table1);
   if (params.orderBy == 'datemodify') {
        query.orderBy('cl.dt_ts', '${params.orderByType}');
    } else  {query.orderBy('clt.id', '${params.orderByType}');}
```

Comment: can you provide your error ?